# How do I solve this initial value heat equation problem, using the heat equation kernal?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, initial-value-problems

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}=k\frac{\partial^2 \theta}{\partial x^2}\\
\theta(x,0)=\exp[-x]
\end{equation}
I know the general solution is 
\begin{equation}
\theta(x,t)=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi kt}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp[{\dfrac{-(x-y)^2}{4kt}}]\exp[-y] dy
\end{equation}
I don't understand what to do next. Please help.

Comment: Can you complete a square maybe? Or partial integration twice.

Comment: I don't understand how you would complete the square on -(x-y)^2-y

Comment: Consider what a constant would be in the context of this integral we want to break out of.

Comment: We want to break of the y but it already looks like its in the complete the square form.

Comment: It isn't because a negative yer is still outside of our control. You just wrote so yourself?

Comment: Could you please show me how to do that, I would highly appreciate it.